# What is the correct way to add dynos to Django/Heroku project?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, dyno

This is continuation of my previous question: [What is the propper way to debug gunicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418145/what-is-the-propper-way-to-debug-gunicorn/72419841#72419841)

Currently I am having error `code=H14 desc="No web processes running"` wihch suggests that there are no dynos. I tried to fix this by doing `heroku ps:scale web=1`, but instead got error: `Scaling dynos... ! ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883519) suggests "simple disable/enable through heroku dashboard". However I can't see any way I can do that. Some other possible solutions suggested that the problem is with the Procfile, its location or its content.

Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn kauppalista.wsgi --log-file -
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
folder my_project
│   requirements.txt
│   runtime.txt
│   folder .git
│   folder my_project-env
│
└───folder my_project
│   │   folder my_project (main Django app)
│   │   folder django app 1
│   │   folder django app 2
│   │   manage.py
│   │   Procfile
```

EDIT:

I also tried moving Procfile one folder up in hierarcy (to same as requirements.txt). At the same time changed Procfile reference to `my_project.my_project.wsgi`. This resulted in dynos to be available so something went right, but then got error: `gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `requirements.txt` and the `runtime.txt` to the location where `manage.py` and `Procfile` is found in your folder structure because, they are all required to be in the project root....
[See here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html)

I also hope that the `kauppalista.wsgi` points to the `main Django app`.
For instance, from the folder structure you provided, the `wsgi.py` file would be found inside this location: `folder my_project > folder my_project > folder my_project(main Django app called kauppalista)`. So the `Procfile` would be;

```
web: gunicorn kauppalista.wsgi --log-file -
```

OR

```
web: gunicorn kauppalista.wsgi
```

Running the `heroku ps` command should also help you to determine the state of the dynos after you apply the changes. In the case it says `'no dyno on app'`, simply disable/enable dynos through the heroku dashboard by loggin in via your web browser.

Remember to add, commit and push your changes to heroku.

Comment: Thanks for input on this one too. After changes first I got: ``remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz``. Then I removed buildpack from heroku web interface (to see if it needed to be reset. ). Then I got: ``remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.``.

Comment: "I also hope that the kauppalista.wsgi points to the main Django app.": manage.py has this line: ``    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'kauppalista.settings')
``. If I understand correctly that should determine what the Procfile should contain.

Comment: Run `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` to set the buildpack to python. The folder structure can be a bit challenging in Heroku. Certain changes in the file arrangement in the project can cause confussion in Heroku's git